# Java Swing - better font smoothing

Tags: java, swing, fonts, smoothing

Is there any possibility to adjust font smoothing in Java swing application?

Here's some comparison:

[image]

The difference isn't huge, but if you look close enough, Adobe Story (and lot of other Flash applications) has stronger and nicer smoothing.

I write text editor in Java, and I would like to achieve such smoothing in my application on JTextPane and JLabels.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593944/how-to-do-font-smoothing-for-awt-swing-application

Comment: not true at all, agreed from this screenshots is difference big, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.m. described `My Java Application`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179955/how-do-you-enable-anti-aliasing-in-arbitrary-java-apps

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what Object you use to display your Text you need to make a custom one of it and Overwrite the method that is responsible for painting your Text

Here is an example of a custom JTextArea

```
public class CustomTextArea extends JTextArea {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        super.paint(g);
    }

}
```

You may need to modify it some more but thats the basic concept

Answer (score -4):

You can use html tags on a Jlabel, like:

```
<html><body><br/><br/><body/><html/>
```

You can for example make a button, like so:

```
button = new JButton("<html><b><u>T</u>wo</b><br>lines</html>");
```

This looks like this: [image]

but here is more about HTML tags [LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

Comment: this is totally unrelated!